# How do you add new data to request.data?

Tags: python, django

What I'm trying to achieve is add `sid` to `request.data` so I can get it to my serializer but I'm not entirely sure how to achieve this. Can I append it somehow or do I have to have a separate serializer just for `sid`?

```
class Test001(APIView):
    def __init__(self):
        self.account_sid = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
        self.auth_token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
        self.twilio_number = 'whatsapp:+14XXXXXXXX'
        self.to_number = 'whatsapp:+14XXXXXXXXX'

    def post(self, request):


        client = Client(self.account_sid, self.auth_token)

        new_message = client.messages.create(
                                from_=self.twilio_number,
                                body=message,
                                to=self.to_number
                            )
        sid = new_message.sid

        serializer = MessageSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
serializer = MessageSerializer(data={**request.data, 'sid': new_message.sid})
```

Answer (score 0):

`request.data` is just a dictionary. You can simply update it with the new items.

```
sid = new_message.sid
data = request.data
data["sid"] = sid
serializer = MessageSerializer(data)
```

Issue would have been if you were using `request.POST` or `request.GET` since they are immutable objects. In that case, you first remove the immutability by creating a copy and then updating it with the new item.

```
sid = new_message.sid
data = request.POST.copy()  #data is now a mutable object.
data["sid"] = sid
serializer = MessageSerializer(data)
```